# 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable when iterate thru a dictionary

Tags: dataframe

I have a dictionary like this

```
dd={888202515573088257: tweepy.error.TweepError([{'code': 144,
                           'message': 'No status found with that ID.'}]),
 873697596434513921: tweepy.error.TweepError([{'code': 144,
                           'message': 'No status found with that ID.'}]),
....,
680055455951884288: tweepy.error.TweepError([{'code': 144,
                           'message': 'No status found with that ID.'}])}
```

I want to make a dataframe from this dictionary, like so

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns = ['twid','msg'])
for k,v in dd:
    df = df.append({'twid': k, 'msg': v},ignore_index = True)
```

But I get TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable. Can someone help me solve this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and it works :

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(dd.items()), columns=['twid', 'msg'])
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, iterating over a dictionary will iterate over the keys. If you want to unpack the (key, value) pairs, you can use `dd.items()`.

In this case, it looks like you don't need the values, so the below should work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['twid'])
for k in dd:
    df = df.append({'twid': k}, ignore_index = True)
```

Alternatively, you can just pass the keys in when creating the DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(dd.keys()), columns=['twid'])
```

Comment: Thanks @Ravi. The first approach won't work, i got the error stated. The 2nd approach (list(dd.keys()) works.

Comment: Note that in the first approach, the loop doesn't have a `v`, e.g. the difference is between `for k in dd:` and `for k, v in dd:`.